# Can I use pygame.time.Clock in an if statement?

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a game in python using pygame. I would like to know if I can use pygame.time.Clock in an if statement to increment a variable like this:

```
mainclock = pygame.time.Clock()
score = 0

while True:
    if mainclock == 0:
        score += 1
```

I would like for score to increase by one every second and if I understand Clock() correctly, this should work but I don't know if or how to use Clock() in an if statement.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: While not a direct answer to your question, you might want to rethink how you handle time. There are 2 common methods: 1. constant frame length. 2. variable frame length. In the first method, you consider each frame to be an X fraction of a second (usually 60) so each time you just add value/X. In the second method, you pass the time delta around and multiply it by the value per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a major misunderstanding of how time and time measurement works in PyGame. You can use the pygame.time.Clock(), but in a totally different way.

NOTE: All Code examples following here are Python 3.4; if you still use Python 2.x and have a problem using the code, feel free to ask.

**A Few Basics**

Your script runs as fast as possible, so basically with every tick of your OS, you have it processed once, which is, depending on your computer's CPU somewhere around 100 times per second.

Now comes the second issue: Clock() is a class in the module "time" of Pygame, it has no value by itself. If you let your programme print "mainclock", the yield will be:  which will NEVER equal 0 and therefore your if-statement will never yield True and thus never be processed at all (and so never add 1 to "score").

Have you understood this part? If not, feel free to ask further questions! These are some very basics you have to understand in order to work with basically any programming language (at least the object-oriented ones).

**How to Solve your Issue**

You will need pygame.time.Clock() in order to solve your issue, but in a different way than what you did. Define a variable as your game's clock, just as you did already with "mainclock":

```
mainclock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

The Clock() class has a method called ".tick()". This method measures the time since the last tick has passed. Try it out: Change your code to this and see what it prints!

```
while True:
    print(mainclock.tick())
```

Or in Python 2.x:
    while True:
        print mainclock.tick()

You will receive a value every time your script has been processed (that's called a "tick"). On my computer this prints a few numbers:

```
>>>
0
35
1
2
2
1
1
1
2
```

etc...

This are the mili-seconds since the script has been processed the last time. That means: when 1000 mili-seconds have passed, a full second has passed. Now to use it for our purpose, we simply have to add them together!

```
mainclock = pygame.time.Clock()
tick_count = 0
score = 0

while True:
    tick_count += mainclock.tick()
    if tick_count >= 1000:
        score += 1
        tick_count = 0
        print(score)
```

Another approach would be to limit the framerate. This you can do by adding a numeral value to the ".tick()" method of the Clock().

```
while True
    mainclock.tick(60)
```

This will cause your script to never run faster than 60 times a second (suggestion: Make your script print mainclock.tick(60) and see what it yields!). Now we can do two things: Either we take that fact and divide one second by 60 or we still measure the time as we did before:

*Approach One - Measure the Time as Before*

```
mainclock = pygame.time.Clock()
tick_count = 0
score = 0

while True:
    tick_count += mainclock.tick(60)
    if tick_count >= 1000:
        score += 1
        tick_count = 0
        print(score)
```

You see, no major change here. We simply tell the script to not run faster than 60 times a second, the rest remains unchanged. If you print the "mainclock.tick(60)", you will now receive values of 16 or 17 per loop as it waits about that time between the ticks to make sure, that it doesn't run more often than 60 times a second.

*Approach Two - Dividing the Seconds...*

Since we told the programme to not run faster than 60 times a second, this also means that one tick takes 1/60th of a second. We can also do this:

```
mainclock = pygame.time.Clock()
tick_count = 0
score = 0

while True:
    tick_count += 1/60 # NOTE: in Python 2.x this has to be: 1.0/60 or 1/60.0!
    if tick_count >= 1:
        tick_count = 0
        score += 1
        print(score)
```

Or alternatively:

```
mainclock = pygame.time.Clock()
tick_count = 1
score = 0

while True:
    tick_count -= 1/60.0
    if tick_count <= 0:
        tick_count = 1
        score += 1
        print(score)
```

Hope, this helps! Otherwise feel free to ask more.